PHP unable to read command line CuRL POST --data
I have a PHP API hosted on a subdomain.
If I submit POST request from PHP the receiving API reads the JSON parameter.
When I submit from the command line it does not.
My PHP Curl call to the API endpoint is this:
<?php
    $url = "https://MySubdomain/MyAPIEndpoint.php";
    $headerfields = array(
        'Accept:application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );
    $postfields = array("orderid" => 123456);
    $postfields = json_encode($postfields);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerfields);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
?>

The command line call is this:
    curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "{"orderid":123456}" https://Mydomain/MyAPIEndPoint.php

The endpoint is reading the JSON passed with this:
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $decoded = (json_decode($content, true));
    $orderid = $decoded['orderid'];

The PHP Curl POST works OK but the command line version is returning a warning Trying to access array offset on null - which indicates that the parameter is not set and therefor not being read by my endpoint code.
The aim of this is to be able to build a command line CuRL command to allow me submit it as a 'fire and forget' call from an exec() statement.

The double quote in your JSON is matching the double quote that delimits the argument. Either escape the nested double quotes:
--data "{\"orderid\":123456}"

or use a different delimiter:
--data '{"orderid":123456}'


The solution is 'half' correct. The single quotes do not work, but the escaped double quotes do. I had tried using the different delimiter: --data '{"orderid":6392842}' but was still receiving the failure.
This worked --data "{\"orderid\":6392842}"
I had read various posts about being able to use double quotes inside double quotes for command line CuRL and, although counter intuitive, tried it.

I can't think of a reason why the single quotes wouldn't work.

Unless your actual code tries to use a variable for the order ID, since variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Ideally you shouldn't create JSON by hand at all, you would use the jq utility.
